# States on the $C^*$ algebra $C_0(X)$

Tags: c-star-algebras

Let $X$ be a locally compact second countable space. Consider the $C^*$- algebra $C_0(X)$. Is it true that there is a one to one correspondence between states on $C_0(X)$ and Borel probability measures on $X$? Or is it true only $X$ is compact? In that case $C_0(X)=C(X)$. I have $Y$ is a compact subspace of $X$ and I have a Borel probability measure on $Y$. Can I extend it to $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. There is a one to one correspondence between states on $C_0(X)$ and **Radon** probability measures. This is the content of the Riesz representation theorem. However, we also have the following theorem:

If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space that is second countable, then every finite Borel measure on $X$ is Radon. See Folland's "Real analysis" theorem 7.8.

Comment: What happens if $X$ is compact? Still it corresponds to Radon Probability measures?

Comment: Yes, if $X$ is compact (Hausdorff), then $X$ is automatically locally compact (Hausdorff) as well so the results still holds.

Comment: How can I do the extension of a Borel probabilty measure defined on a compact subspace $Y$ of $X$ to $X$? Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about that. Sorry.

Comment: @AAh I was mistaken when I wrote my answer. I missed the second countability hypothesis. This ensures that Borel measures are automatically Radon when they are finite on compact sets.